# Dynamics 365 v9 (on premise) and Plugins using .NET 4.6.2

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dataverse

I'm wondering if anyone has been able to build a plugin using .NET 4.6.2 on Dynamics 365 V9 on premise using the latest Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies (currently 9.0.2.34) . We tried to do that but we are getting a runtime error.

The version of Dynamics we are testing this on is Microsoft Dynamics 9.0.3.7 on premise

[image]

We tried the following combinations:

- **.NET 4.5.2 - Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 8.2.0.2**: Works fine!
- **.NET 4.5.2 - Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.5**: Works fine!
- **.NET 4.5.2 - Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.34**: Plugin registration tool gives the error “Currently, Microsoft Dynamics 365 requires the .NET Framework version 4.6.2 for plug-in assemblies. Rebuild the assembly with the .NET Framework version 4.6.2 and try again.”
- **.NET 4.6.2 - Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.34**: Plugin registration is able to register the plugin but we get the following error at runtime: "Could not load file or assembly ', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4ec06d9a40abb18' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

NOTE: We also tried to deploy exactly the same assembly in Dynamics Online/Dataverse and it works fine!

In all cases we are using Isolation Mode as Sandbox and location as Database (see screenshot below)

[image]

We also switched on assembly binding logging and got the following logs:

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.

LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Dynamics 365\Server\bin\Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.WorkerProcess.exe.Config

LOG: Using host configuration file:

LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.

LOG: Post-policy reference: , Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4ec06d9a40abb18

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Dynamics 365/Server/bin/.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Dynamics 365/Server/bin//.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Dynamics 365/Server/bin/.EXE.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Dynamics 365/Server/bin//.EXE.

It appears that the Sandbox service is trying to find the assembly locally rather than in the database. The same assembly works just fine if we build it with target framework as .NET 4.5.2

Any help on this is much appreciated

Thanks

Juan

Comment: Do you have some dependencies with another assemblies in your plugin?

Comment: Public key token b4ec06d9a40abb18 not the one of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll. Try and find out which external assembly is being referenced. It may not be merged with your plugin dll.

Comment: any specific reason for using 4.6.2?

Comment: @Arsen I don't have any dependency with another assemblies, bear in mind that the same assembly works just fine for Dynamics Online/ Dataverse.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen the public key token b4ec06d9a40abb18 is actually the assembly I'm trying to register as a plugin

Comment: @GuidoPreite main reason for upgrading to 4.6.2 is that 4.5.2 is going out of support next year (26 April 2022), I'm doing a full review of all our third party packages and I would rather tackle the issue now.

Comment: Another interesting fact, the Sandbox service can't find our assembly, it looks as if it's trying to search it in the local system rather in the database as it does for 4.5.2. 

I opened the Sandbox executable from the server using JustDecompile and the Sandbox service executable itself has been compiled targeting .NET 4.5.2.

What I'm trying to figure out is if Dynamics 365 On premise doesn't support .NET 4.6.2 full stop or if there is anyone in the community that is running plugins compiled in .NET 4.6.2 and if so, how?

Comment: @Juan Stoppa I'm using plugins compiled in .NET 4.6.2 in on-premise environment, it registers and runs with no problem for me

Comment: @JuanStoppa: Try making a brand new plugin with only a minimum of code. If that does not work with 4.6.2 either, your server or Dynamics deployment may have an issue. Plugins on 4.6.2 have been working fine for many years already.

Comment: @Arsen what version of dynamics on premise are you using?

Comment: thanks @HenkvanBoeijen, could it be our version of Dynamics, it's quite old (9.0.2.34), we'll try in a newer version

Comment: @JuanStoppa: I don't think it's in the version. I have worked with 4.6.2 since at least Dynamics 8.1.

Comment: Thanks for the info @ Arsen and @ HenkvanBoeijen, I think the issue is with our plugin, I'll let you know when we find the root cause

Comment: I have used 9.0.2.34 CoreAssemblies with 4.6.2 on on-premise but we use XrmToolkit in VS2019 to deploy or configure plugin/steps. Try something very simple like throw exception for plugin trace log to test. if(something != null)
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Fake Exception");

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this issue, it went away when we upgraded to Dynamics 365 v9.1